# Fastest way for calculating rank of 2*2 matrix?

Tags: performance, r, matrix, rank

The recommended way to calculate the rank of a matrix in R seems to be `qr`:

```
X <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
Y <- matrix(c(1.0, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
qr(X)$rank
[1] 2
qr(Y)$rank
[1] 1
```

I was able to improve efficiency by modifying this function for my specific case:

```
qr2 <- function (x, tol = 1e-07) { 
  if (!is.double(x)) 
  storage.mode(x) <- "double"
  p <- as.integer(2)
  n <- as.integer(2)
  res <- .Fortran("dqrdc2", qr = x, n, n, p, as.double(tol),
                  rank = integer(1L), qraux = double(p), pivot = as.integer(1L:p), 
                  double(2 * p), PACKAGE = "base")[c(1, 6, 7, 8)]
  class(res) <- "qr"
  res}

qr2(X)$rank
[1] 2
qr2(Y)$rank
[1] 1

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(qr(X)$rank,qr2(X)$rank,times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
         expr    min     lq median     uq      max
1  qr(X)$rank 41.577 44.041 45.580 46.812 1302.091
2 qr2(X)$rank 19.403 21.251 23.099 24.331   80.997
```

Using R, is it possible to calculate the rank of a 2*2 matrix even faster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just get rid of more stuff you don't need (because you know what the values are), don't do any checks, set `DUP=FALSE`, and only return what you want:

```
qr3 <- function (x, tol = 1e-07) {
  .Fortran("dqrdc2", qr=x*1.0, 2L, 2L, 2L, tol*1.0,
           rank = 0L, qraux = double(2L), pivot = c(1L,2L), 
           double(4L), DUP = FALSE, PACKAGE = "base")[[6L]]
}
microbenchmark(qr(X)$rank,qr2(X)$rank,qr3(X),times=1000)
# Unit: microseconds
#          expr    min      lq  median      uq     max
# 1  qr(X)$rank 33.303 34.2725 34.9720 35.5180 737.599
# 2 qr2(X)$rank 18.334 18.9780 19.4935 19.9240  38.063
# 3      qr3(X)  6.536  7.2100  8.3550  8.5995 657.099
```

I'm not an advocate of removing checks, but they do slow things down.  `x*1.0` and `tol*1.0` ensure doubles, so that's kind-of a check and adds a little overhead.  Also note that `DUP=FALSE` can potentially be dangerous, since you can alter the input object(s).

Comment: `fortune(98)` - well, times 4 I suppose.

Comment: @BenBarnes: I used the time I saved to look at lolcats on the interwebs.

Comment: I am optimizing performance of a function that I need to run a few million times in a simulation. `qr` is used inside a while loop in this function. So, in the end those microseconds some up to hours.

Answer (score 3):

We can do even better using RcppEigen.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using   Eigen::Map;
using   Eigen::MatrixXd;
using   Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR;
typedef  Map<MatrixXd>  MapMatd;

//calculate rank of a matrix using QR decomposition with pivoting 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int rankEigen(NumericMatrix  m) {
   const MapMatd  X(as<MapMatd>(m));
   FullPivHouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(X);
   qr.setThreshold(1e-7);
   return qr.rank();
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark(rankEigen(X), qr3(X),times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
         expr   min    lq median    uq    max neval
 rankEigen(X) 1.849 2.465  2.773 3.081 18.171  1000
       qr3(X) 5.852 6.469  7.084 7.392 48.352  1000
```

However, the tolerance is not exactly the same as in LINPACK, because of different tolerance definitions:

```
test <- sapply(1:200, function(i) {
  Y <- matrix(c(10^(-i), 10^(-i), 10^(-i), 10^(-i)), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
  qr3(Y) ==  rankEigen(Y)
})

which.min(test)
#[1] 159
```

The threshold in FullPivHouseholderQR is defined as:

> A pivot will be considered nonzero if its absolute value is strictly
>   greater than |pivot|≤  threshold * |maxpivot| where maxpivot is the
>   biggest pivot.

Answer (score 2):

Let me now if this function lacks of some precautions in this case, but it seems to be quite fast

```
myrank <- function(x)
  if(sum(x^2) < 1e-7) 0 else if(abs(x[1,1]*x[2,2]-x[1,2]*x[2,1]) < 1e-7) 1 else 2

microbenchmark(qr(X)$rank, qr2(X)$rank, qr3(X), myrank(X), times = 1000)
Unit: microseconds
         expr    min     lq median      uq      max
1   myrank(X)  7.466  9.333 10.732 11.1990   97.521
2  qr(X)$rank 52.727 55.993 57.860 62.5260 1237.446
3 qr2(X)$rank 30.329 32.196 33.130 35.4625  178.245
4      qr3(X) 11.199 12.599 13.999 14.9310  116.185

system.time(for(i in 1:10e5) myrank(X))
   user  system elapsed 
   7.46    0.02    7.85 
system.time(for(i in 1:10e5) qr3(X))
   user  system elapsed 
  10.97    0.00   11.85 
system.time(for(i in 1:10e5) qr2(X)$rank)
   user  system elapsed 
  31.71    0.00   33.99 
system.time(for(i in 1:10e5) qr(X)$rank)
   user  system elapsed 
  55.01    0.03   59.73
```

Comment: Thank you. Your function is faster than Joshua's, but seems not to give exactly the same result as `qr(X)$rank`, when used in my actual test case (which I did not give here). It is not easy to find out, when and why it gives different results. Since the speed difference between your and Joshua`s function is not that big, I just take his function. But I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Roland, you are right, I have just compared my function and `qr`. `1e-7` is the problem here: for rank 0 I'd say it should be `== 0`, then there are more problems with rank 1 because `qr` outputs 2 even when all entries are about `1e-300`, which is correct. But product of such entries is 0 in R, and `myrank` returns 1, so this is not a valid solution anymore. Dividing rows might work but then then function becomes slow.